# Unwanted Text in LinkedIn Auth screen

Tags: php, codeigniter, linkedin-api

I have integrated the LinkedIn login using oAuth in my webapp. The webapp is developed on CodeIgniter.

The authorization/login screen gives a text which is not correct. Attached is an image[LinkedIn Auth Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjSW1.jpg) with screenshot. The Login is working great otherwise.

I need help to understand where is the text coming from?

I have a view class with the Sign in with LinkedIn button, which when clicked directs it to the controller function as below:

```
public function login_with_linkedin(){
        if($this->session->has_userdata('email') &&   
        this->session->userdata('email')!= '' &&  
        $this->session->userdata('login_type')==='signup'){
            $this->session->set_userdata('path','inside 
            login_with_linkedin() signup'); 
            redirect(site_url('user/signup_complete'), 'refresh');
            $this->session->set_userdata('login_type','login');
        }else if($this->session->has_userdata('email') && 
        $this->session->userdata('email')!= '' && 
        $this->session->userdata('login_type')==='login'){
            $this->session->set_userdata('path','inside  
            login_with_linkedin() login');
            redirect(site_url(''), 'refresh');
        }else{
             $this->session->set_userdata('path','inside 
             login_with_linkedin() authenticate');
             $user=$this->users->login_with_linkedin();
             }
    }
```

Comment: Which text is not correct?  The screenshot doesn't make this clear.

Comment: In the screenshot a grey rectangle has marked the text. i.e Cliklayer is the text. But then after that there is LN login as well which is not correct. Hope that clarifies

Comment: You should clarify that in your question.  You can click the `edit` link below the question (directly above these comments) to update your question with this information.  Be as explicitly clear as you can be about what is not correct, and about what you expect it to look like.  The gray rectangle was an incredibly subtle indication of the issue.  Remember, people who read your question don't know the details of your project, nor what is or is not correct.

Comment: Sure Michael. I hope its clear to you now. Can you provide me any headway in the matter?

Answer (score 0):

It appears there's a problem with the application's logo image being displayed, so the text that's coming up is the image's alternate text, which is your application name.

Go into your application settings and try uploading a new logo image.